# Compilation Error in procedure of Oracle 10

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle10g

I wrote simple stored procedure in oracle. but its shows procedure created with compilation errors.

My code is:

```
Create  PROCEDURE test
 (
 ID_no varchar
 )
 AS
 BEGIN
 SELECT Student.name , Student.dept,   from Student
 WHERE Student.id=ID_no
 END;
 /
```

Please help me to solve this problem .

Comment: You're missing a ; after the where clause

Answer (score 0):

1) Extra comma -

> SELECT Student.name , Student.dept,   from

2) semicolon after select is missing -

```
WHERE Student.id=ID_no
 END;
```

3) If you get the values from query, you should put it to something -

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test(id_no VARCHAR) AS
   s_name   student.name%TYPE;
   s_dept   student.dept%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT student.name, student.dept
     INTO s_name, s_dept
     FROM student
    WHERE student.id = id_no;
END;
/
```

Comment: Using your code I got Procedure created with compilation Error.

Comment: Change the code. But anyway - oracle errors has codes starting with "ORA-" and has short descriptions. Always write the error code.